# Primary Key count Count in LINQ very slow

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I thought LINQ to SQL was tuned for performance?

The following LINQ to SQL for counting is very poor

```
Dim uniqueFactors As Integer = db.LargeTable.Distinct.Count
```

produces:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[LargeTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[ID] % @p0) = @p1
```

How every the fastest way to count the number of records based on a primary key is

```
SELECT  @totalRowCount = rows
FROM    sysindexes
WHERE   id = OBJECT_ID('LargeTable')
    AND indid < 2
```

So the question, how can I ensure that LINQ to SQL performs a count quickly when asking for Count(*)?

Comment: Are you sure that the query and TSQL are from the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you expect. If you ask for the "Distinct.Count" on a table, you're instructing LINQ to do exactly what it does. Since that will result in a table scan, it will be slow for larger tables.

The SELECT COUNT(*) is the only way SQL Server (and therefore LINQ) can give you an **exact, up-to-date** count of the rows in the table.

Selecting a rows from sysindexes (or preferably: sys.partitions in SQL Server 2005 and up - the "sysindexes" views are being deprecated) will give you a **approximate** number - but that's not guaranteed to be absolutely correct and up to date.

So basically, what LINQ is missing, is a "UseApproximationForPerformancesSake" switch. That might be helpful at times - but then again, you can always use that little chunk of SQL and query the database yourself, if you need a speedy and only approximate response.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I had a somehow similar problem, I tried these and worked out better :

child.count(x=> x.paretnID == inputParentID) child.where(x=> x.parentID == inputParentID)

my original code which took around 15-20 seconds on each iteration was: return (isEdit) ? db.ChasisBuys.Single(x => x.ChasisBuyID == long.Parse(Request.QueryString["chbid"])).Chasises.Count(y => y.Bikes.Count > 0 && y.ColorID == buyItems[(int)index].ColorID && y.ChasisTypeID == buyItems[(int)index].ChasisTypeID).ToString() : "-";

new code which runs good is :

```
    **return (isEdit) ? db.Chasises.Where(x => x.ChasisBuyID == long.Parse(Request.QueryString["chbid"])).Count(y => y.Bikes.Count > 0 && y.ColorID == buyItems[(int)index].ColorID && y.ChasisTypeID == buyItems[(int)index].ChasisTypeID).ToString() : "-";**
```

Database has around 1000 records in chasises , about 5 in chasisBuys and about 20 in Bikes. my opinion is that Linq to SQL queries does not do preevaluations such in logical statements which for instance if you write "return a && b && c;" if statement a is false other statements are not evaluated and I was expecting such thing in linq to sql but it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your TSQL; have you omitted part of the LINQ query (i.e. the "where") from the question? No matter how I try, I get pretty normal TSQL that perfoms ok...

Since the primary key is unique, why not just:

```
int count = db.LargeTable.Count();
```

Otherwise; have you tried *selecting* the primary key?

```
int count = db.LargeTable.Select(x=>x.Id).Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your linq to "db.LargeTable.<strike>Distinct.</strike>Count();"

Should produce the following SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[LargeTable] AS [t0]
```

Which should use an index scan instead of a table scan. Which should be much quicker.

Comment: Nope, this causes a full table scan.  It times out on 3 million records in a table  :-(

Comment: Check your indexes. On my server if counts a table of 1 million records almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple COUNT which is all I wanted and don't want to wait forever don't use the Entity methods.

Use a simple LINQ to SQL format.

```
int largeCount = (from o in db.LargeTable
                       where o.SomeField == somVal
                       select o).Count();
```